# Subtract each raster in a list by one before it

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have a list of rasters named like so:

```
19940506.tif
19950506.tif
19960506.tif
19970506.tif
```

and I want to subtract 19950506 by 19940506 and 19960506 by 19950506 etc.

I can do this manually with something like this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\pathway_to_rasters'
May1List=arcpy.ListRasters('*.dat')
outpath=r'F:\outpath'
outRaster = Raster(May1List[1]) - Raster(May1List[0]) 
out='19950506_19940506'
outpath=os.path.join(outpath,out + '.tif')
outRaster.save(outpath)
```

but if would like to try and find a way to automate this in a loop if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the indices of the list, but start at the second raster:

```py
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\pathway_to_rasters'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')

dirOut = r'F:\outpath'

for x in range(1, len(rasters)):
    print 'Subtracting {} from {}'.format(rasters[x-1], rasters[x])
    raster = Raster(rasters[x]) - Raster(rasters[x - 1])

    rasterOut = os.path.join(dirOut, '{}_{}.tif'.format(rasters[x], rasters[x-1]))
    if arcpy.Exists(rasterOut):
        print '\tThe output raster {} already exists.'.format(rasterOut)
    else:
        print '\tSaving to {}'.format(rasterOut)
        raster.save(rasterOut)
```